# How to make the transition from relative position to fixed position smooth

Tags: jquery

I want to sticky a div at the top of the page when the page is scrolled down. Here is the JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       var navHeight = $('#fixed-menu' ).offset().top;
       $(window).scroll(function() {
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('#fixed-menu').addClass('stick-menu').fadeIn("slow");
             }
             else { 
                 $('#fixed-menu').removeClass('stick-menu').fadeIn("slow");              
             }
        });
        });
```

The jQuery function is working perfectly and it's striking the div (a navigation menu) at the top of the page. But when it reaches the top it makes a small jump. I understand that it's because the position of the div is changing from relative to fixed.

Is there a workaround so that I can make the div stick smoothly.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ayanize/ywhvctot/24/

Thanks

Comment: please include your html & css too ... enough code to reproduce the issue. Make a snippet here or a Codepen / Jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I missed that. Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ayanize/ywhvctot/24/. If you scroll down slowly, you will see a jump in the red section when the menu sticks at the top